# I want to be able to trade 1 contact per 500 dollars of equity,Ill paste my strategy in below.If anyone can help i would be grateful

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to be able to trade 1 contact per 500 dollars of equity,i cant use the percentage of equity or dollar amount it has to be in contacts the futures i trade only work with contracts.The code for my strategy is below. It works god its just a macd crossover strategy.Thank you!

```
//@version=5
strategy("MACD Futures", overlay=false, initial_capital = 5000,currency=  currency.USD)

//SL&TP Settings

ON_OFF1 = input.bool(false, title="TP_SL ON/OFF",group="Profit Settings")
stopPercent = input.float(defval = 40, step = 1, title = "SL")
takePercent = input.float(defval =40, step = 1, title = "TP")

// Getting inputs

fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", defval=12,group="MACD Settings")
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", defval=26,group="MACD Settings")
src = input(title="Source", defval=close,group="MACD Settings")
signal_length = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing",  minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9,group="MACD Settings")
sma_source = input.string(title="Oscillator MA Type",  defval="SMA", options=\["SMA", "EMA"\],group="MACD        Settings")
sma_signal = input.string(title="Signal Line MA Type", defval="EMA", options=\["SMA", "EMA"\],group="MACD   Settings")

// Calculating

fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? ta.sma(macd, signal_length) : ta.ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal

//Trading Time Settings

ON_OFF = input.bool(true, title="Time Filter ON/OFF",group="Time Settings")
inSession = input.session(title="Time Filter",defval="0830-1300", group = "Time Settings")

//Colored Background

paintBg = input.bool(title="Paint Background?", defval=true,group = "BackGround Highlighter")
timezone = input.session(title="Timezone To Highlight", defval="1600-0830", group = "BackGround Highlighter")

 // InSession() determines if a price bar falls inside the specified session

InSession(sess) =\> na(time(timeframe.period, sess + ":1234567")) == false

// Color the background of each relevant session and/or bar
bgcolor(color=InSession(timezone) and paintBg ? color.new(color.blue, 95) : na, title="Not Insession")

//Date Range Settings

useDateFilter = input.bool(false, title="Filter Date Range of Backtest",
group="Backtest Time Period")
backtestStartDate = input.time(timestamp("1 Jan 2020"),
title="Start Date", group="Backtest Time Period",
tooltip="This start date is in the time zone of the exchange " +
"where the chart's instrument trades. It doesn't use the time " +
"zone of the chart or of your computer.")
backtestEndDate = input.time(timestamp("1 Jan 2025"),
title="End Date", group="Backtest Time Period",
tooltip="This end date is in the time zone of the exchange " +
"where the chart's instrument trades. It doesn't use the time " +
"zone of the chart or of your computer.")

inTradeWindow = not useDateFilter or (time \>= backtestStartDate and time \< backtestEndDate)

Session = not ON_OFF or InSession(inSession)
// Plot colors
col_macd = input(#2962FF, "MACD Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="MACD")
col_signal = input(#FF6D00, "Signal Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="Signal")
col_grow_above = input(#089981, "Above   Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_fall_above = input(#089981, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_grow_below = input(#f23645, "Below Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
col_fall_below = input(#f23645, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
hline(0, "Zero Line", color=color.new(#787B86, 50),linestyle=hline.style_solid)
plot(hist, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=(hist\>=0 ? (hist\[1\] \< hist ? col_grow_above :  col_fall_above) : (hist\[1\] \< hist ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below)))
plot(macd, title="MACD", color=col_macd, linewidth =2 )
plot(signal, title="Signal", color=col_signal,linewidth =2)
quantity=

//Long Entries

if (ta.crossover(hist, 0)and Session  and inTradeWindow)
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Long")
if (ON_OFF1)
strategy.exit(id="Long Close",from_entry = "Long",profit=takePercent , loss=stopPercent)

//Short Entries

if (ta.crossunder(hist, 0) and Session  and inTradeWindow )
strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, comment="short" )
if (ON_OFF1)
strategy.exit(id="Short Close",from_entry = "short",profit=takePercent , loss=stopPercent)

//Close Short Time
closeshort = not Session
if (closeshort )  
strategy.close(id= "short")

//Close Long Positions time

closelong = not Session
if (closelong )
strategy.close(id="Long")
```

I dont know where to start with this im new to pine script.

Comment: hello. there are two or more indicators merge. some v4 and some v5. start by [converter v4 into 5](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_5.html#v4-to-v5-converter)

Comment: Hi,im confused this is writen and works in pinescript v5? @Gu5tavo71

Comment: If you have already begun coding and are stuck on a specific coding issue please provide a properly submitted script example that is compilable